# providing current user to all templates in django project

Tags: django, django-templates, django-authentication

I wonder if there is a way to provide all templates in django application with the current user variable so that I manage login and logout functionality in all pages.
It is a very common practice so there must be an obvious solution I have missed.
I know about the `RequestContext` Class but that means I have to add it to every view in the application which seems impractical.
May be a custom template tag?

Answer (score 3):

There's a template context processor for this: `django.core.context_processors.auth`. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth), you can access the current user and the permissions in the templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use a custom tag to achieve that.
Note that by default the custom tag has no access to the `request` object and therefore to the user data. In order to gain access to the `request` you can define the custom tag with the `takes_context` attribute and grab the request from the context:

Something like:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('userdata.html', takes_context = True)
def userdata(context):
    request = context['request']
    user = request.user
    return {'user':user}
```

Comment: true... you'd have to make sure you have ContextResponse using one of the methods illustrated here: http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2008/may/10/getting-requestcontext-your-templates/

Comment: btw: @msc's  answer (using the auth processor) will also require passing along a `RequestContext`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `{{ request.user }}` to display the name of the current user,  or maybe for example `{{ request.user.is_authenticated }}` to find out if it's an AnonymousUser or not.